# Rotational invariance of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let

$$u(x)=\int\limits_{|y|<r}\frac{(x-y)^{\perp}}{|x-y|^2}dy$$

When $|x|>r$, someone said that by the rotational invariance of function $u$, so we have:

$$u(x)=\frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|}|u(x)|$$

Here $x^{\perp}=(x_2,-x_1)$. Why is this?

Comment: What's $\left(\,x - y\,\right)^{\perp}$ ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin I said it is (x2-y2,-x1+y1)

Comment: If you depict the field you are integrating the situation will be pretty clear. By applying the same rotation to $x$ and $y$ you may assume that $x$ lies on a fixed ray.